# How to implement comments in Django attached to a user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am attempting to add comments to posts (in this site posts are called beets) and would like each comment to be from a user and attached to that user.  A user should have a list of comments they have made.  The post the comment is on should show the comments as well.

I have gotten as far as I can add comments through the admin page, but I can't add them through the form on the site.  I do not receive an error message, but the comments do not show up in the admin or the site.

Also, even though the comments post from the admin screen, they do not show up on the site.

Models.py

```
class Beets(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=240)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Beet by {self.author}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('beets:beets-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        """
        Likes for the beet
        :return: Integer: Likes for the company
        """
        return self.likes.count()

    def likes_as_flat_user_id_list(self):
        return self.likes.values_list('id', flat=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    beet = models.ForeignKey(
        Beets, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=240)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

views.py - just the comment part

```
def add_comment_to_beet(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        beet = get_object_or_404(Beets, pk=id)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=beet)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('beets:beets-detail', beet.id)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'beets/add_comment_to_beet.html', {'form': form})
```

beets_detail.html

```
<hr />
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'beets:add_comment_to_beet' object.id %}">
        Add comment</a>
    {% for comment in object.comment.all %}
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
        <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
        <p>{{ comment.content|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

forms.py

```
class BeetsModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=240,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "class": "content form-control",
                "id": "content-field"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Beets
        fields = ['content']


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content']
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'beets'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', BeetsListView.as_view(), name="beets-list"),
    path('<int:pk>/', BeetsDetailView.as_view(), name='beets-detail'),
    path('create/', BeetsCreateView.as_view(), name="beets-create"),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', BeetsUpdateView.as_view(), name="beets-update"),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', BeetsDeleteView.as_view(), name="beets-delete"),
    path('<int:id>/like/', like, name="beets-like"),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserBeetsListView.as_view(), name='user-beets'),
    path('<int:id>/comment/', add_comment_to_beet, name='add_comment_to_beet')
]
```

Comment: Are you using html `form` tag to add a new comment? Please also include your `BeetsDetailView` view code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are setting `user` or `beet` in your new `Comment` object (but I can't understand why that doesn't give an error). Anyway, I'd have expected

```
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.save( commit=False)  # returns new unsaved comment object
    comment.user = user
    comment.beet = beet  
    comment.save()     
    return redirect('beets:beets-detail', beet.id)
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: The only part of this code that I changed was comment.user to comment.author.  Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in an easier manner than actually making your own comments model. Try implementing django comments instead: https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I am really trying to implement this without using Django Comments Framework.